# Can't clear Recycle Bin, too many files

Tags: windows, windows-10

Due to a problem while zipping a large file I ended up with around half a million tiny files in my recycle bin. When I try to empty the bin the computer crashes after a while and after alerting me that it has not enough RAM.

I've tried several methods of emptying the bin, to no avail. 
I tried the following approaches:

1. used tools like CCleaner, NirCMD and others;
2. ran CMD as admin and tried `rd /s /q C:*recycl* > nul` which only lead to Windows telling me that the syntax would be incorrect;
3. tried `rd /s /q C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` which leads to Windows telling me that it can't find it;
4. selected *show hidden objects* in the Explorer since I wanted to delete the Recycle Bin there but I can't find it on any of my three drives.

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit by the way. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Try just changing the allowed size of the recycle bin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VACil.png) that should avoid having to actually try emptying the bin.

Comment: He will need to empty the recycle bin eventually...

Comment: @Burgi - The idea is that the system would reduce the size of the current recycle bin, allowing him to empty it, its a worth a try

Comment: I agree - it was worth a try. Unfortunately it didn't work though. I reduced the size to 1 MB but it still takes ages to open the bin. It used to take 2-3 hours and just now it looks like nothing changed about that.

Comment: Unhide hidden system files and then navigate to the C drive and try to delete  $RECYCLE.BIN from the root of C.

Comment: I know this might seem like an obvious thing but have you tried deleting the files in smaller batches?

Comment: try: del /f/s/q folder > nul 
and 
rmdir /s/q folder

Comment: When you run `RmDir /S "C:\RECYCLER"` it first loads the entire bin into RAM and then it crashes. So it never gets around to deleting it. I have around 30million json files in my recycle bin totaling to 55gb. The life of a data scientist

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "rd /s /q C:\$RECYCLE.BIN" in a command prompt not the Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Just run Disk Cleanup (it's under drive properties). Check the Recycle Bin option even if it says 0 bytes and you'll have it empty in seconds.